# What happens if we re-enter boss areas in Mario + Rabbids?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

After defeating the bosses, I saw many times that the heroes explore worlds excluding the boss areas.

What happens if we enter boss areas after we defeat them? **(Note: You can show the footage about it)**